# Wrong layout in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

In my app I use several UICollectionView. When the number of cell aren't so much I've an issue that's explained from this image:

[image]

I'm using this library for Horizontal layout [FullyHorizontalCollectionView](https://github.com/philippeauriach/fullyhorizontalcollectionview). Every time I reload the data of the UICollectionView I use the follow code `[self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout]`, but nothing changes.
There's someone that has the same issue and can help me?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Add these lines in your viewDidLoad method, if collection view flow layout not working.**

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.scrollDirection = .vertical //.horizontal
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 1, left: 1, bottom: 1, right: 1)
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 1.0
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 1.0
    //your collection view object
    myCollectionView.setCollectionViewLayout(layout, animated: true)
    myCollectionView.reloadData()
}
```